# Was the "Monkey-fighting snakes on this Monday through Friday plane" dub edit Samuel L. Jackson's idea?

Tags: dialogue, dubbing, snakes-on-a-plane

The 2006 film *[Snakes on a Plane](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0417148/)* had a version edited for US television that censored profanity, often with hilarious replacements. The most famous is Samuel L. Jackson's line:

> Enough is enough! I have had it with these monkey-fighting snakes on this Monday through Friday plane!

One of the top YouTube comments, with over 1,400 upvotes, says the following:

> This was Samuel Jackson's decision. He felt that if he was going to be censored, he at least wanted it to be entertaining.

Is there any proof that it was actually Jackson's decision to say this line?

Comment: I contend that the scene in question was actually a reshoot.  If you watch his mouth and listen to the words, his mouth is definitely not saying "Motherphuqqin'".  Turn the sound off and see.  You won't get any proof, and a google search turned up nothing, but it seems reasonable that Jackson was given the leeway in the reshoot to make up his own edit.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Your theory could be tested by comparing it to the uncensored version. As talented as Samuel L Jackson is, he's not going to have his facial position and such be exactly the same to the millimeter between the two takes. If it indeed appears to be a reshoot, then I'd accept that as an answer since it proves that it was actually Jackson who said it (rather than a sound-alike dubber), which means it's plausible that it was his idea.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iY7D6rKjoKM It wouldn't be unprecedented for the makers of a movie to make an amusingly censored version